# Communication between unrelated directives

Tags: angularjs

As part of my layout, I have a banner directive:

```
.directive('appBanner', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.$on('BANNER_ID_UPDATED', function (e, data) {
                // code to fetch banner from db here
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Now, depending on the page or content that's displayed, the banner may have to change. I've been trying to use events to communicate between my banner directive and my other directives. It will fire the following event:

```
$scope.$emit('BANNER_ID_UPDATED', id);
```

This doesn't always work. When I place some `console.log` calls, it seems that the event is sometimes fired before it is being listened for. How can I fix this, or how can I otherwise ensure communication between two unrelated directives?

Comment: Create a service that handles fetching the banner information and inject the service into directives that need it.

Comment: Can it be that it is not always working because you are emitting on the scope and not the rootScope? emit will go downwards, so your banner directive's scope should be child olf  the emitting directive's scope.

Comment: @eesdil I'm not entirely sure as I'm not too familiar with how events work in Angular. When I put a `console.log` before the `$scope.$on` and before each `$scope.$emit`, I will sometimes see the message `event fired` before the message `listening for events`. e.g. the code that fires the event is loaded and executing before the code that makes the part listen to events is. I have managed to solve it by using a service though, as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of potential pitfalls when using events. For this particular case I would propose to use a service (you can bundle it with banner directive into the banner submodule).

Your directive can then register the listener to trigger banner update. Then call some `updateBannerData(data)` of this service which will call the listener to trigger banner change. Here is some code directly from my head (hopefully without errors...)

```
.factory('bannerService', function() {
  var bannerService = {
    listener: null,
    onUpdate(listener) {
      bannerService.listener = listener;
    }
    updateBannerData: function(data) {
      if(listener) {
        listener(data);
      }
    }
  };
  return bannerService;
})
// inject bannerService here:
.directive('appBanner', [function (bannerService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    controller: function ($scope) {
      bannerService.onUpdate(function (data) {
        // code to fetch banner from db here
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: When @Explosion_Pills suggested I use a service I did some searching and altered my existing service (which handled fetching from WebAPI) to do what you describe. That works perfectly and is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the help.